# visibility: hidden in IE not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm using this CSS for bootstrap carousel prev-next buttons on the slider:

```
.carousel .carousel-control{
   visibility: hidden;
  }
  .carousel:hover .carousel-control{
   visibility: visible;
  }
```

While it works in Chrome and Firefox, it doesn't in IE10. Is there a workaround available for this?

Edit: Tested [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tS9PL/3/) and it works in IE10, so it must be something else on website. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just created a fiddle, and its working fine in IE9, Can you check in IE10 also? http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/2XQEL/

Comment: @Surjith SM it works yes, I added my own as well.

Comment: You should debug it by removing some other styles. Can you provide a complete demo link?

Comment: Works on IE10, I think an other style disable this, try add `!important` to be sure of that. After you can search the other css which make it disable (don't forget to remove !important in your final css)

Comment: @kevpoccs Adding !important doesn't make it work either on IE

Comment: Could you test with a separate, new html page with that css applied, and then test it out on IE. see if it works. if it doesn't then there is a problem with other parts of your css

Answer (score 2):

I think something other in your css make this disable because `visibility` is compatible with IE10 [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/CSS/visibility) it require IE4+

An alternative could be :

```
.carousel .carousel-control{
  opacity: 0;
}
.carousel:hover .carousel-control{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Can you do a jsfiddle ?